# Display woocommerce sub-categories when on a parent category page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories

I am trying to display all of the child product categories, while the parent  category page is selected.

At the moment, within the wordpress customiser settings I have the 'Shop page display' to show categories, and the 'Category display' to show subcategories.

When I select the store page, I am presented with the list of categories - lets say one of them is music... great! When I then select music, I would expect to see a set of new child categories, such as Rock, Dance, Pop ect. However at the moment I am just presented with all of the individual products.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

On the shop page you can display only categories, categories with products or only products. If you want to display product categories on your Shop page instead of just products, follow these steps:

1. Click on Appearance > Customize
2. Then go to WooCommerce > Product Catalog
3. Select “Show categories” from Shop Page Display
4. Click on Save Changes

Show WooCommerce Sub Categories on Shop Page
Categories – Subcategories – Products. If you want your shop page to display in that order. Follow these steps:

1. Click on Appearance > Customize
2. Then go to WooCommerce > Product Catalog
3. Select “show subcategories” from Category Display
4. Click on Save Changes

Also Check : https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-categories/

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your function.php

```
add_action( 'display_product_subcategories', 'product_subcategories', 1 );
function product_subcategories( $args = array() ) {

    $parentid = get_queried_object_id();
    $args = array(
        'parent' => $parentid
    );
    
    $terms = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args );
    
    if ( $terms ) {
        echo '<div>';
    
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            echo '<li class="category">';                 
                woocommerce_subcategory_thumbnail( $term );
                echo '<h2>';
                    echo '<a href="' .  esc_url( get_term_link( $term ) ) . '" class="' . $term->slug . '">';
                        echo $term->name;
                    echo '</a>';
                echo '</h2>';
            echo '</li>';
        }
    
        echo '</ul>';
    }
}
```

Then summon the function in your template page e.g. archive-product.php

```
<?php do_action( 'display_product_subcategories' ); ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can make your own category template.

The file should be [taxonomy-product_cat.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/2.6.0/templates/taxonomy-product_cat.php)
Also look at the [archive-product.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/2.6.0/templates/archive-product.php)

Your custom code should go around the `woocommerce_product_loop_start`

Also check the [woocommerce codex](https://docs.woocommerce.com/documentation/plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce-codex/)

---

And to show categories on shop page -

It's easy, just go to `'WooCommerce -> Settings'` link from side bar admin menu & select `'Catalog'` tab & then tick 2 check boxes `"Show subcategories on the shop page"` & `"When showing subcategories, hide product" -> click 'Save Changes'` button at bottom. That's it! You are Done!

Now visit 'Shop' page you'll be able to see categories.

Hope this helps.